# How to use xBind with ViewModelLocator?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

Want to use the new `x:Bind` compile time binding with MVVMLight and `ViewModelLocator` class.

How to change this to use x:Bind?

```
DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Source doesn't seem to be supported, so this failed:

```
DataContext="{x:Bind Path=Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

So how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use following approach.
I leave the conventional binding for the `DataContext` of a `View` so in your example leave

```
DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

But in the code behind I use that `DataContext` to set up a property of the `ViewModel` to use in all `x:Binding` on that same `View`, like this:

```
private LoginViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as LoginViewModel;
```

That way when you need x:Bind in your view you can do:

```
{x:Bind ViewModel.UserName, Mode=OneWay}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose this property through your code behind like

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public LoginViewModel Login
    {
        get
        {
            return Locator.Login;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Than in your xaml you can consume this login property without Source like

```
DataContext="{x:Bind Login}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you give your Page.DataContext a name...

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:SettingsPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

With that in place, you can `DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel.Login}"`